# Pass File object to background.js from content script or pass createObjectURL (and keep alive after refresh)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

My goal is to upload a file in the background task with a file coming from the content script.

I figured it's not possible to pass a File object directly from content script to the background because `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` JSON serialize the data.

It's possible to pass a string url to the file with `URL.createObjectURL`, which works. But the URL is tied to the document in the window on which it was created (current tab content script). If I refresh, navigates away, close the tab those urls are destroyed.

Read the entire file with FileReader and keep in memory is not an option because it'll crash the extension on large files.

**Questions:**

1. Keep the `URL.createObjectURL` alive?
2. Pass File object to background?
3. Upload a file in the background task with a file from the content script?
4. Pass file link to popup and submit form there, which then run in background?

Comment: Q1: Not possible. Q2 and Q3. Fully answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211073/chrome-extension-crashes-when-i-try-to-upload-a-big-file. Q4: What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks @RobW, I used your answer from this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086918/does-chrome-runtime-support-posting-messages-with-transferable-objects/21101597#21101597 and by your input also made the object transferable by slicing it first. You can submit it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `SharedWorker` to create a communication channel between your content script and background script that allows you to transfer DOM objects such as `File`s. For an example, see the code in [Does chrome.runtime support posting messages with transferable objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086918/does-chrome-runtime-support-posting-messages-with-transferable-objects/21101597#21101597)

A quick test shows that it is indeed possible to send a `File` to the background, but also shows that its internal state is corrupted: You *can* read the contents of the file using `FileReader`, but you cannot upload the file through `XMLHttpRequest`.

I've found a work-around though: Assuming that your `File` is stored in the `file` variable, you can use `file.slice(0, file.size)` instead of `file` to get a `Blob` that is still backed by the file *and* usable in `XMLHttpRequest` even after passing it to the background page.