# Preparing Blob for chrome messaging: blob.text() and back again results in corrupted file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, blob

I am trying to pass a `Blob` from a chrome extension to a javascript web application using the [Chrome Message API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage). Inspired by a [former Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582573/implement-cross-extension-message-passing-in-chrome-extension-and-app) I want to convert the blob to text in order to send the content and filetype as an object via the messaging API to the website and eventually reassemble the `Blob`.

When executing the following snippet of code, however, I'm unable to reassemble the `Blob`. Basically the `URL.createOjectURL()` method should return valid `blob:`-URLs for both, `blob` and `new_blob`. While working on both objects, the `new_blob` URL results in a corrupted image (grey square) while the URL for `blob` shows the correct image. (On the receiving end the same problem occurs, of course).

```js
fetch(request.url)
    .then(r => r.blob())
    .then(blob => {
    var filetype = blob.type
    blob.text().then(text => {
        var message = {
            blob: text,
            url: request.url,
            filetype: filetype
            }

        var new_blob = new Blob([message.blob], {type: message.filetype})

        console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        console.log(URL.createObjectURL(new_blob))

        ...
        sendResponse(message)
        })

    })
```

Comment: Remove `blob.text().then(text => ` and just use URL.createObjectURL(blob)

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion. That's how I started, however chrome has a security feature resulting in a `Not allowed to load local resource` error: When sending the URL from the extension to a website, the website is not allowed to access the local file.

Comment: Using `.text()` on binary data seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @m.a. you need to fetch in the content script, then dispatch the blob using CustomEvent. Another, much faster solution is shown [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/UyNHEHQKlJA/m/it_eC58DAwAJ).

Answer (score 0):

While the solution using `blob` is still not working, I found an alternative way to solve the problem: Using `base64`. There is example code available [on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Jonarod/77d8e3a15c5c1bb55fa9d057d12f95bd):

```
const BlobToBase64 = function(blob){
... (see gist) ...
}

fetch(request.url)
    .then(r => r.blob())
    .then(blob => BlobToBase64(blob))
    .then(base => {
       sendResponse(base)
       })
```

Comment: FWIW, the built-in FileReader can convert blob to base64 much faster and simpler.