# How to pass a blob from a Chrome extension to a Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

**A Little Background**

I've been working for a couple of days on a Chrome extension that takes a screenshot of given web pages multiple times a day. I used [this](https://github.com/mrcoles/full-page-screen-capture-chrome-extension) as a guide and things work as expected.

There's one minor requirement extensions can't meet, though. The user must have access to the folder where the images (screenshots) are saved but [Chrome Extensions don't have access to the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802032/how-can-a-chrome-extension-save-many-files-to-a-user-specified-directory). Chrome Apps, on the other hand, do. Thus, after much looking around, I've concluded that I must create both a Chrome Extension and a Chrome App. The idea is that the extension would create a blob of the screenshot and then send that blob to the app which would then save it as an image to a user-specified location. And that's exactly what I'm doing — I'm creating a blob of the screentshot on the extension side and then sending it over to the app where the user is asked to choose where to save the image.

**The Problem**

Up to the saving part, everything works as expected. The blob is created on the extension, sent over to the app, received by the app, the user is asked where to save, and the image is saved.... THAT is where things fall apart. **The resulting image is unusable.** When I try to open it, I get a message that says *"Can't determine type".* Below is the code I'm using:

1. First ON THE EXTENSION side, I create a blob and send it over, like this:

   ```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
       APP_ID, /* I got this from the app */
       {myMessage: blob}, /* Blob created previously; it's correct */
       function(response) {
         appendLog("response: "+JSON.stringify(response));
       }
    );
   ```
2. Then, ON THE APP side, I receive the blob and attempt to save it like this:

   ```
   // listen for external messages
   chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
     function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
       if (sender.id in blacklistedIds) {
         sendResponse({"result":"sorry, could not process your message"});
         return;  // don't allow this extension access
       } else if (request.incomingBlob) {
         appendLog("from "+sender.id+": " + request.incomingBlob);

         // attempt to save blob to choosen location
         if (_folderEntry == null) {
            // get a directory to save in if not yet chosen
            openDirectory();
         }
         saveBlobToFile(request.incomingBlob, "screenshot.png");

         /*
         // inspect object to try to see what's wrong
         var keys = Object.keys(request.incomingBlob);
         var keyString = "";
         for (var key in keys) {
            keyString += " " + key;
         }
         appendLog("Blob object keys:" + keyString);
         */

         sendResponse({"result":"Ok, got your message"});
       } else {
         sendResponse({"result":"Ops, I don't understand this message"});
       }
     }
   );
   ```

   Here's the function ON THE APP that performs the actual save:

   ```
   function saveBlobToFile(blob, fileName) {
     appendLog('entering saveBlobToFile function...');
     chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(_folderEntry, function(entry) {         
       entry.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function(entry) {         
         entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
           //writer.onwrite = function() {
           //   writer.onwrite = null;
           //   writer.truncate(writer.position);
           //};
           appendLog('calling writer.write...');
           writer.write(blob);                       
           // Also tried writer.write(new Blob([blob], {type: 'image/png'}));
         });
       });
     });
   }
   ```

There are no errors. No hiccups. The code works but the image is useless. What exactly am I missing? Where am I going wrong? Is it that we can only pass strings between extensions/apps? Is the blob getting corrupted on the way? Does my app not have access to the blob because it was created on the extension? Can anyone please shed some light?

**UPDATE (9/23/14)**
Sorry for the late update, but I was assigned to a different project and could not get back to this until 2 days ago.

So after much looking around, I've decided to go with @Danniel Herr's suggestion which suggests to use a SharedWorker and a page embedded in a frame in the app. The idea is that the Extension would supply the blob to the SharedWorker, which forwards the blob to a page in the extension that is embedded in a frame in the app. That page, then forwards the blob to the app using parent.postMessage(...). It's a bit cumbersome but it seems it's the only option I have.

Let me post some code so that it makes a bit more sense:

**Extension:**

```
var worker = new SharedWorker(chrome.runtime.getURL('shared-worker.js'));
worker.port.start();
worker.postMessage('hello from extension'); // Can send blob here too
worker.port.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
   $('h1Title').innerHTML = event.data;
});
```

**proxy.js**

```
var worker = new SharedWorker(chrome.runtime.getURL('shared-worker.js'));
worker.port.start();

worker.port.addEventListener("message",
   function(event) {      
      parent.postMessage(event.data, 'chrome-extension://[extension id]');
   }
);
```

**proxy.html**

```
<script src='proxy.js'></script>
```

**shared-worker.js**

```
var ports = [];
var count = 0;
onconnect = function(event) {
    count++;
    var port = event.ports[0];
    ports.push(port);
    port.start(); 

    /* 
    On both the extension and the app, I get count = 1 and ports.length = 1
    I'm running them side by side. This is so maddening!!!
    What am I missing?
    */
    var msg = 'Hi, you are connection #' + count + ". ";
    msg += " There are " + ports.length + " ports open so far."
    port.postMessage(msg);

    port.addEventListener("message",       
      function(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < ports.length; ++i) {
            //if (ports[i] != port) {
                ports[i].postMessage(event.data);
            //}
        }
    });
};
```

**On the app**

```
context.addEventListener("message", 
    function(event) {
        appendLog("message from proxy: " + event.data);
    } 
);
```

So this is the execution flow... On the extension I create a shared worker and send a message to it. The shared worker should be capable of receiving a blob but for testing purposes I'm only sending a simple string.

Next, the shared worker receives the message and forwards it to everyone who has connected. The proxy.html/js which is inside a frame in the app has indeed connected at this point and should receive anything forwarded by the shared worker.

Next, proxy.js [should] receives the message from the shared worker and sends it to the app using parent.postMessage(...). The app is listening via a window.addEventListener("message",...).

To test this flow, I first open the app, then I click the extension button. I get no message on the app. I get no errors either.

The extension can communicate back and forth with the shared worker just fine. The app can communicate with the shared worker just fine. However, the message I sent from the extension->proxy->app does not reach the app. What am I missing?

Sorry for the long post guys, but I'm hoping someone will shed some light as this is driving me insane.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys. I found the solution to be to convert the blob into a binary string on the extension and then send the string over to the app using chrome's message passing API. On the app, I then did what Francois suggested to convert the binary string back a blob. I had tried this solution before but I had not worked because I was using the following code on the app:

```
blob = new Blob([blobAsBinString], {type: mimeType});
```

That code may work for text files or simple strings, but it fails for images (perhaps due to character encoding issues). That's where I was going insane. The solution is to use what Francois provided since the beginning:

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(blobAsBinString.length);
for (var i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
   bytes[i] = blobAsBinString.charCodeAt(i);            
}             
blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: mimeString});
```

That code retrains the integrity of the binary string and the blob is recreated properly on the app.

Now I also incorporated something I found suggested by some of you here and RobW elsewhere, which is to split the blob into chunks and send it over like that, in case the blob is too large. The entire solution is below:

**ON THE EXTENSION:**

```
function sendBlobToApp() {  

  // read the blob in chunks/chunks and send it to the app
  // Note: I crashed the app using 1 KB chunks. 1 MB chunks work just fine. 
  // I decided to use 256 KB as that seems neither too big nor too small
  var CHUNK_SIZE = 256 * 1024;
  var start = 0;
  var stop = CHUNK_SIZE;      

  var remainder = blob.size % CHUNK_SIZE;
  var chunks = Math.floor(blob.size / CHUNK_SIZE);      

  var chunkIndex = 0;

  if (remainder != 0) chunks = chunks + 1;           

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
      var message = {
          blobAsText: fr.result,
          mimeString: mimeString,                 
          chunks: chunks 
      };          
      // APP_ID was obtained elsewhere
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(APP_ID, message, function(result) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              // Handle error, e.g. app not installed
              // appendLog is defined elsewhere
              appendLog("could not send message to app");
          } 
      });

      // read the next chunk of bytes
      processChunk();
  };
  fr.onerror = function() { appendLog("An error ocurred while reading file"); };
  processChunk();

  function processChunk() {
     chunkIndex++;         

     // exit if there are no more chunks
     if (chunkIndex > chunks) {
        return;
     }

     if (chunkIndex == chunks && remainder != 0) {
        stop = start + remainder;
     }                           

     var blobChunk = blob.slice(start, stop);

     // prepare for next chunk
     start = stop;
     stop = stop + CHUNK_SIZE;

     // convert chunk as binary string
     fr.readAsBinaryString(blobChunk);
  } 
}
```

---

**ON THE APP**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.id in blacklistedIds) {
      return;  // don't allow this extension access
    } else if (request.blobAsText) {                  
       //new chunk received  
      _chunkIndex++;                   

      var bytes = new Uint8Array(request.blobAsText.length);                     
      for (var i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
         bytes[i] = request.blobAsText.charCodeAt(i);            
      }         
      // store blob
      _blobs[_chunkIndex-1] = new Blob([bytes], {type: request.mimeString});           

      if (_chunkIndex == request.chunks) {                      
         // merge all blob chunks
         for (j=0; j<_blobs.length; j++) {
            var mergedBlob;
            if (j>0) {                  
               // append blob
               mergedBlob = new Blob([mergedBlob, _blobs[j]], {type: request.mimeString});
            }
            else {                  
               mergedBlob = new Blob([_blobs[j]], {type: request.mimeString});
            }
         }                         

         saveBlobToFile(mergedBlob, "myImage.png", request.mimeString);
      }
    }
 }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this really comprehensive solution. I like this approach, and so far it seems to be working great.

Comment: Doesn't work. chunks desynchronize.
Need a way to receive everything in correct order

Answer (score 7):

> Does my app not have access to the blob because it was created on the
>   extension? Can anyone please shed some light?

Exactly! You may want to pass a `dataUrl` instead of a `blob`. Something like this below could work:

```
/* Chrome Extension */

var blobToDataURL = function(blob, cb) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
    var dataUrl = reader.result;
    var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
    cb(base64);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  };

blobToDataUrl(blob, function(dataUrl) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(APP_ID, {databUrl: dataUrl}, function() {});
});

/* Chrome App */

function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]),
        mimeString = dataURL.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var blob = new Blob([ia], {type: mimeString});
    return blob;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request) {  
  var blob =  dataURLtoBlob(request.dataUrl); 
  saveBlobToFile(blob, "screenshot.png");
});
```

Comment: No :(

dataURL is what I tried first. It doesn't work because the dataURL I have looks something like this: filesystem:chrome-extension://' + chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id') + '/persistent/' + fileName. The app does NOT have access to the created image because it's in the extension's sandbox. At least that's what I thought the issue was when I couldn't display the image on the app using the dataURL.

Comment: This might be helpful. Let me know if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582573/implement-cross-extension-message-passing-in-chrome-extension-and-app

Comment: @LeonAlpha if you sending blob to app, why can't you send dataURL?

Comment: Thank you Daniel Herr. I'll take at look at that option tomorrow and report back to see if it works.

@vux777 I'm having issues sending the blob to the app. It seems like everything goes over but the resulting image is unusable. Then when I tried dataURL, it doesn't work either. The expected ';' ':' and ':' in dataURL are missing and the code provided to decode it into a blob fails.

Comment: @DanielHerr Hey Daniel, I've updated my question to reflect what I've done so far. I have the code in place but the message I sent is lost mid way and I can't figure out where. Would you please see my edit and see if anything comes to mind? This is really driving me insane. I can't figure it out. Spent like 10 hours on it already.

Thanks again.

Comment: You might want to ask in the original question, I was just wondering if that actually worked.

Answer (score 3):

I am extremely interested in this question, as I am trying to accomplish something similar.

these are the questions that I have found to be related:

1. [How can a Chrome extension save many files to a user-specified directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802032/how-can-a-chrome-extension-save-many-files-to-a-user-specified-directory?lq=1)
2. [Implement cross extension message passing in chrome extension and app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582573/implement-cross-extension-message-passing-in-chrome-extension-and-app)
3. [Does chrome.runtime support posting messages with transferable objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086918/does-chrome-runtime-support-posting-messages-with-transferable-objects/21101597#21101597)
4. [Pass File object to background.js from content script or pass createObjectURL (and keep alive after refresh)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293216/pass-file-object-to-background-js-from-content-script-or-pass-createobjecturl-a/24303394#24303394)

According to Rob W, in the first link:

"Chrome's fileSystem (app) API can directly write to the user's filesystem (e.g. ~/Documents or %USERPROFILE%\Documents), specified by the user."

If you can write to a user's filesystem you should be able to read from it right?

I haven't had the opportunity to try this out, but instead of directly passing the file blob to the app, you could save the item to your downloads using the chrome extension downloads api.

Then you could retrieve it with the chrome app filesystem api to gain access to it.

Edit:

I keep reading that the filesystem the api can access is sandboxed. So I have no idea if this solution is possible. It being sandboxed and Rob W's description of "writing directly to the user's filesystem" sound like opposites to me.

Edit:

Rob W has revised his answer here: [Implement cross extension message passing in chrome extension and app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582573/implement-cross-extension-message-passing-in-chrome-extension-and-app).

It no longer uses a shared worker, and passes file data as a string to the backend, which can turn the string back into a blob.

I'm not sure what the max length of a message is, but Rob W also mentions a solution for slicing up blobs to send them in pieces.

Edit:

I have sent 43 mbs of data without crashing my app.

Comment: That's a thought. Now, I went through the API's a while back and found that extensions only have access to temporary storage or permanent storage, both of which are inaccessible to the user and inaccessible to other apps. That is, each extension runs in a sandbox and other apps don't have access to the files it creates (or at least that's what I remember). That is why I need an app, because the app can write anywhere. My problem now is getting the blob of the image from the extension to the app. My only hope now is a SharedWorker but it's not working as can see here.

Comment: Assuming Rob W was correct, why would you still need to send the blob?

You could just download the files that you need into your chrome's default download directory using your extension, and then use the filesystem api in your app to access them. No blob required, you only work with the actual file you wanted.

Comment: fileSystem API still needs the user to select a folder to access. This would be kind of strange for the user.

Comment: That does sound less than optimal.

Comment: Guys thanks for your input! @markain I have to check the downloads api. Everything I've read thus far points to permanent or temporary storage. But if the downloads api allows me to 1-create directories and 2-save to those directories without user interaction then I have my solution. I'm not sure I can though. @ Xan The user would choose a location only once via the app UI. On the code above, the block 'if (_folderEntry != null) { openDirectory(); }' accomplishes this. The user chooses a folder where images are to be saved. This works very nicely. My issue is that the images are useless now.

Comment: Rob W changed his answer for sending blobs to an app, see my edits above.

Answer (score 2):

That's really an intresting question. From my point of view it can be done using these techniques:

1. First of all you should convert your blob to arraybuffer. This can be done with [FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341912/javascript-how-to-go-from-blob-to-arraybuffer), and it is async operation
2. Then here comes some magic of [Encoding API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer---String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API), which is currently available on stable Chrome. So you convert your arraybuffer into string. This operation is sync
3. Then you can communicate with other extensions/apps using Chrome API [like this](https://github.com/1999/listen/blob/master/src/background/core.js#L69-L73). I am using this technique to promote one of my apps (new packaged app) using another famous legacy app. And due to the fact that legacy packaged apps are in fact extensions, I think everything will be okay.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Sorin. I'll take a look at your solution tomorrow and report back to let you know if it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. As much as I tried it I couldn't get it to work. I was able to send the array buffer just fine but the resulting image was unusable and could not be opened. I've edited my question to show what I'm trying to do now. I'm using a SharedWorker and a frame in the app as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582573/implement-cross-extension-message-passing-in-chrome-extension-and-app. Your insights into this (or a reason as to why your previous suggestion did not work) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you